# Unexpected Error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, out-of-memory

This occurs after i have been running Oracle Pack Eclipse with Weblogic 12 after about 2 hours, repeatedly...what went wrong, and how can i fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error (under other circumstances) a while ago. 
It turned out to be a problem with a non existant java version. 
Check the path specified in your eclipse.ini points to the javaw.exe you really want to use.

Comment: thanks calon, im trying it out now. can you upvote my question so i can accept your answer? thanks!

Comment: also should i use the javaw in ...\jdk160_29\bin or ...\jdk160_29\fastdebug\bin ?

Comment: I have no experience with the fastdebug java builds. I guess that it depends on what you want to use. Using the fastdebug stuff will probably require you to use the \jdk160_29\fastdebug\bin dir. But like I said this is a guess.

Comment: I am not allowed to comment on others, yet. So I will put a comment to your comments to Panos here.
You could try to use jconsole in the jdk to check the memory usage (and more) in your java process, e.g. eclipse. 
Note that this doesn't help if eclipse crashes right from the start, since you have to connect jconsole to a running process.
If you are using windows, you could use the eclipsec.exe, which often prints out stuff like PermGen errors directly.

Answer (score 0):

try increasing Xmx. 512 is not much since you run Weblogic.

Comment: what is the suggested number? Xmx1024 ?

Comment: Depends on the project you run and your pc. 1024 is good for me. My solution is for the case where your app crashes (out of memory errors etc). If it doesn't start at all then #Calon 's solution is the one.

Comment: ahhh...i see. in case the app crashes ..do i have to increase Xms or MaxPermSize?

Comment: Xmx helps if you are facing OutOfMemory Errors (Exceptions). It still won't help if you application leaks memory. 

In you case I guess the right answer is calon's.